# Is Wiretap better to use for asynchronous calls than the ProducerTemplate ASYNC methods of Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

My use case for the async flow is:

1. Client calls Apache Camel and immediately responds with an acknowledgement
2. Camel then forwards client request to an external system
3. Camel forwards the external system response back to Client (to a Client API made to await this request/call from Camel)

I have tried load testing 2 solutions for this using JMeter:

- **Producer Template Async Send Body**: 13K TPS with 10% Error
- **Wiretap EIP**: 13K TPS with 1% Error

Is there any drawbacks to using the Wiretap instead of Producer Template ASYNC methods? Is there something I can do to put the Producer Template at par with the Wiretap?

EDIT:

Code for Wiretap (RouteBuilder)

```java
from("some:where")
  .wiretap("external:call")
  .to("bean:someBean?method=acknowledge");
```

Code for ProducerTemplate

```java
@Autowired
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

public Response asyncCall(Request request) {
  producerTemplate.asyncSend("external:call", request);
  Response response = new Response();
  response.setMessage("Acknowledged");
  return response;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi @Namphibian I just updated it with the code